# Filtering out a unique list containing one specific criteria

Tags: sql, filter, distinct

I have one table called 'Domains'. Column A (domainnames) contains a list of various domain names. Column B (status) contains it's 'status'. The Status can be either Active,Ended,Blocked,Cancelled. A domain name can can be listed in Column A more than once, and is not limited to having only one type of Status. Note, that if a domain is listed in Column A more than once, and each instance of it has the status Cancelled, all occurrences of that domain should appear in the results.

I want to pull out a list of all domains that 'only' have the status cancelled. They cannot have the status cancelled, AND also another type of status. In this example below, it should return domain5.com only.

Domainnames

Domain1.com 
Domain2.com 
Domain1.com 
Domain4.com 
Domain5.com

Status

Active 
Ended 
Cancelled 
Blocked 
Cancelled

Many thanks!

Comment: What will be the output if domain5.com is available in table for two times with the status as 'cancelled'

Comment: Apologies for not addressing that. As long as that domain does not have any other type of status other than Cancelled, it should list all occurrences of that domain name. It should not be limited to returning a completely distinct list of domain names.

Comment: From what i asked in my above comment and what you explained in your above comment , what i understood is that the result set should contain 'domain5' two times as no other kind of status has been updated on it and both the existing rows have status as 'cancelled'. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT  domainname FROM DomainsTable
WHERE 
Status = 'Canceled'
```

Comment: that wat i understanded from ur question

Comment: Apologies for not addressing that. As long as that domain does not have any other type of status other than Cancelled, it should list all occurrences of that domain name. It should not be limited to returning a completely distinct list of domain names.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `not exists` clause to demand that there are no rows for the same domain in another status:

```
select  *
from    Domains d1
where   status = 'cancelled'
        and not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Domains d2
        where   d1.domainname = d2.domainname
                and d2.status <> 'cancelled'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out with following sql query:

```
select Domainnames  from Domains 
            where Status ='cancelled' AND
            Domainnames  NOT IN (SELECT Domainnames  from Domains where Status <> 'cancelled')
```

Comment: This logic seemed to work. I had to integrate other tables as well, so this was the easiest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select * from domains d 
where d.status = 'cancelled' and 
( select count(*) from domains where domainnames = d.domainesnames) = 1 ;
```

If the `count equals to 1` that means there is only one row for the `d.domainnames` and i.e is the current row in the select query.